# Python For Loop over XML node List not a sequence

Tags: python, for-loop

I am relatively new to python and having trouble some trouble looping over a nodes children using xml.dom. I want to do this:

```
dom = parse("synth_options.xml")
root = dom.documentElement
child_nodes = root.childNode

for index, node in child_nodes:
    #do stuff with index and node
```

However, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "synth.py", line 142, in <module>
    for index, node in child_nodes:
TypeError: iteration over non-sequence
```

Strangely, this works:

```
for node in child_nodes:
    #do stuff with index and node
```

I can post more code if it would be helpful, but I don't think there is anything else relevant. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to get both the index and the value, you can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, node in enumerate(child_nodes):
```

`enumerate` returns a tuple of the list indices and values.

Example of use:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for index, value in enumerate(l):
    print index, value


0 a
1 b
2 c
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can't accept your answer yet, but this works.  Why exactly is this necessary?